# Dojo widgets not loading in FireFox

Tags: jsp, dojo

We are having an issue loading dojo widgets in our application. The dojo library is uploaded to web publisher and its folder structure is like- www.wp-mydemopath.com/web/fw/tools/ssue/ui/1.6/auessome/dojo

We are loading the dojo componets in a jsp that is common across all the pages. We are loading the dojo components in the following way-

```
djConfig = {
            isDebug: false,
            debugAtAllCosts: false,
            parseOnLoad: true,
            baseUrl: "http://www.wp-mydemopath.com/web/fw/tools/ssue/ui/1.6/auessome/dojo/",
            modulePaths: {
                xwt: "www.wp-mydemopath.com/web/fw/tools/ssue/ui/1.6/auessome/xwt/"
            }
```

here we define this in a script tag-

```
src="http://www.wp-mydemopath.com/web/fw/tools/ssue/ui/1.6/auessome/dojo/dojo.js"
```

Once we have registered the dojo  module path and dojo.js, we are loading all the required dojo widgets in the following way-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");

    dojo.require("dijit.dijit");

    dojo.require("xwt.widget.toolbar.Toolbar");

    dojo.require("xwt.widget.form.FilteringSelect");

    //and functionality will be defined here
</script>
```

Issue is, when the above code is used in Internet explorer, its working fine. But if we use the same code in Firefox its failing to load the dojo widgets. We are getting the following error in the firebug console-

> could not load dojo.parser, last tried as ./parser.js.

Like wise it is unable to load any of the widgets. 
Please help in resolving this issue. Looked the same issue for many people in different blogs, but none has got a resolution.
I found that the firefox will put a restriction, I tried by passing this restriction by setting the parameter to false. Even that did not work. Though it works, it is not a feasible solution as we cannot ask end users to set this in their browsers. Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

kumarji Alluri

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things first..

[djconfig-deprecated](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/1.6.html#djconfig-deprecated)

Are you using crossdomain? There's no need to reference the paths as absolute. Also, baseUrl defaults to the location of dojo.js so strike that out.

Infact, the 'xwt' namespace is positioned as siblings to dojox, dojo and dijit so you shouldnt actually need to define it..

I suggest using boiler from that very page. "data-" prefix is the new mojo mon, following should suffice:

```
<script src="http://www.wp-mydemopath.com/web/fw/tools/ssue/ui/1.6/auessome/dojo/dojo.js" 
  data-dojo-config="isDebug: false,debugAtAllCosts: false,parseOnLoad: true"><!-- //required for FF3 and Opera (TidyHTML in JSP) --></script>
```

The reason for this comment `<!-- //required for FF3 and Opera (TidyHTML in JSP) -->` is, that JSP servers most often tidies up the output, detecting faulty DOM hierachy and closing tags; Problem being that the script tag should not be self-closing