# dojo custom build

Tags: dojo

I have created custom build using the below form.profile.js file

```
dependencies ={
layers: [
{
name: "form.js",
dependencies: [
"dijit.form.Button",
"dijit.form.Form",
"dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
]
}
],
prefixes: [
[ "dijit", "../dijit" ]
]
};
```

i got the form.js and form.js.uncompressed.js files

when i try to use the form.js in my jsp it is giving me error like this

Could not load class 'dijit.form.ValidationTextBox

Below is the jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link href="./scripts/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.myClass{
font-size:14px;
}
</style>
<script src="./scripts/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
<script src="./scripts/dojo/form.js"></script>
<script>
//dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
//dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
dojo.ready(function(){

});
function showDialog(){
alert("Clicked!!");
//dijit.byId("dialog1").show();
}

function changed(){
alert(dijit.byId("select1").value);
dijit.byId("name").attr("value",dijit.byId("select1").value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">

<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="name" propercase=true trim=true required=true  invalidMessage="Please Enter a valid value" />
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" value="Click" id="b1" onclick="showDialog()">Click</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know where i went wrong.

Comment: Which version of dojo are you using? also, if using tidyhtml with the jsp, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072376/dojo-widgets-not-loading-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try a full script tag for dojo.js, and "dojo.require()" for everything else:

```
<script 
   type="text/javascript" 
   src="scripts/dojo/dojo.js"
   djConfig="parseOnLoad:true,isDebug:true">
   dojo.require("scripts/dojo/form.js");
</script>
```

Comment: Tried the same but no luck :(

Comment: this will not run, cannot have innerText and src at same time though the meaning of answer shows perfectly clear